# factory isnt recognized by controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have a controller, "ListController", which needs to be populated with server side data.

```
app.controller("ListController", function(){ 
  var bar = this; 
  bar.venues = MyFactory.load(); 
}
```

and I wanted to get the json array from the server, so i was thinking to create a factory leveraging "$http" as such:

```
app.factory("MyFactory", ["$https", function($https){
  var myService = {};
  myService.load = function(){
    $http.get("scripts/Query.php").success( function(rows){ 
      myService.rows = rows;
      return myService.rows;
    };
  };
  return myService;
}]);
```

So, i was thinking that MyFactory would be able to be called from inside the app controller.

**app is the same variable, of type:  angular.module("BarMe", []);**

The error i get in my javascript is:  *MyFactory is undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't inject factory in your controller.

Try like this

```
app.controller("ListController", function(MyFactory){ 

}
```

More over your method has a callback direct assign won't bring you any data

Try like this

```
MyFactory.load().then(function(data){
  bar.venues = data;
});
```

You also have to return $http with response from factory

```
myService.load = function(){
   return $http.get("scripts/Query.php").success( function(rows){ 
      return rows;
    };
  };
```

Comment: i have it setting myService.rows = rows, and then returning essentially rows.   Kinda redundant.    So, the success i was having `return  rows;` but it seems that it still gives me an injector error for MyFactory

Comment: can you provide your fullcode with html ?? it'll be better if you can provide jsfiddle

Comment: Oh, i seemed to get it working.  Your way worked.  It seems like i was having issues like you said.  I thought i mightve not needed the "then" function.  Thanks!